# 1200px media query to contain content; with background colours remaining 100% width

Tags: css

I am stuck trying to find an appropriate solution; without adding a lot of divs to my markup.

I need the content at the 1200px media query; to stay fixed at 1200 and in the centre. Which is working.

However, the row containers with background colours, shadows etc. to stay 100% of the width.

Any guidance on how best to solve this problem; would be very much appreciated.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; 
}
input[type=text] {
    font-size: 1.5rem; padding: 0 0.25em 0 1.2em; height: 4rem;
    line-height: 4rem; width: 50vw; color: #333;
    background: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}
.head_sticky {
    position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 100;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .col-m-1 { width: 16.67%; } .col-m-2 { width: 33.33%; } .col-m-3 { width: 50.00%; }
    .col-m-4 { width: 66.67%; } .col-m-5 { width: 83.33%; } .col-m-6 { width: 100%; }
    [class*='col-'] {
        float: left; padding: 5px 16px 5px 0;
    }
    .search_form_cls {
        height: 4.5rem; line-height: 4.5rem; font-size: 3rem;
        color: black; border: none; background: transparent;
    }
    input[type=text] {
        width: 75vw;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .col-t-1 { width: 12.5%; } .col-t-2 { width: 25%; } .col-t-3 { width: 37.5%; }
    .col-t-4 { width: 50%; } .col-t-5 { width: 62.5%; } .col-t-6 { width: 75%; }
    .col-t-7 { width: 87.5%; } .col-t-8 { width: 100%; }
    [class*='col-'] {
        float: left; padding: 5px 24px 5px 0;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-d-1 { width: 8.33%; } .col-d-2 { width: 16.66%; } .col-d-3 { width: 25% }
    .col-d-4 { width: 33.33% } .col-d-5 { width: 41.66% } .col-d-6 { width: 50%; }
    .col-d-7 { width: 58.33%; } .col-d-8 { width: 66.66%; } .col-d-9 { width: 75%; }
    .col-d-10 { width: 83.33%; } .col-d-11 { width: 91.66% } .col-d-12 { width: 100%; }
    [class*='col-'] {
        float: left; padding: 5px 28px 5px 0;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .A3_row {
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
[class*='col-']:first-of-type {
    padding-left: 16px;
}
[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 16px;
}
.A3_row {
    display: flex; background-color: white;
}
.A3_row [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex; align-items: center; flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.A3_row::after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: table;
}
.navigation_link
    text-decoration: none; color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='head' class='A3_row shadow_bottom head_sticky'>
            <div class='col-m-1 col-t-1 col-d-1'>
                <span class='navigation_link'>&#9776;</span>
            </div>
            <div class='col-m-2 col-t-2 col-d-2'>
                LOGO            
            </div>
            <div class='col-m-3 col-t-5 col-d-9 t-end'>
                    <input autocomplete='off' name='q' class='search_form_m' type='text' placeholder='Search' value='' maxlength='100'>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='A3_row' style='background-color:blueviolet; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold;'>
            <div class='col-m-6 col-t-8 col-d-12'>Heading</div>
        </div>
        <div class='A3_row' style='background-color:blueviolet;'>
            <div class='col-m-6 col-t-8 col-d-12' style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; width: 100%;">Content</div>
        </div>
        <div class='A3_row' style='background-color:gold; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold;'>
            <div class='col-m-6 col-t-8 col-d-12'>Heading</div>
        </div>
        <div class='A3_row' style='background-color:gold;'>
            <div class='col-m-6 col-t-8 col-d-12'  style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; width: 100%;">Content</div>
        </div>
        <div class='A3_row' style='background-color:lightseagreen; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold;'>
            <div class='col-m-6 col-t-8 col-d-12'>Heading</div>
        </div>
        <div class='A3_row' style='background-color:lightseagreen;'>
            <div class='col-m-6 col-t-8 col-d-12'  style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; width: 100%;">Content</div>
        </div>    
        <div class='A3_row'>
            <div class='col-m-6 col-t-8 col-d-12' style='align-items: flex-start'>
                <span>FOOTER</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you importing your CSS from Bootstrap or writing your own custom media query(s)?

Comment: @Jtuck Good question - I wrote my own. I believe I hacked together a self-contained example using the Run Code Snippet. My entire grid system is within the CSS snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSS-only solution using `calc()`:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .A3_row {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1200px) / 2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1200px) / 2);
  }
}
```

This `width` declaration makes the "row" `100%` of the width of its containing block while the `padding-*` declarations ensure the "content" is `1200px`.

- See [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) (MDN)

Comment: I would not have arrived at your elegant solution in a million years. Thank you. I was fiddling around with ::before and ::after divs which made my skin crawl. Can I assume the divisble by 2, is forcing the content to remain centered?

Comment: @dimButTries Yes, because `padding-left` has the same value as `padding-right`. E.G., if the viewport width at 100% is 1920px then `1920 - 1200` is `720` so both `padding-left` and `padding-right` is 360.